# How to make My gui start the server when the sign on button is pressed

Tags: python, sockets, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

The server doesn't seem to start even though in theory it should work? I've implemented it the same way it starts the actual GUI, it should get the IP and the PORT from the entry boxes, however it doesn't start up like it does for the GUI when I start the server up from a different file. So how could I get the server to start when the sign on button is pressed.

Here is the GUI code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import customtkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from CHAT_GUI_FUNCTIONS import chat_gui, server_gui


def server_boot(server_ip, server_port):
    destination = (server_ip, server_port)

    if destination == 0:
        server_gui(server_ip1(), server_port1())
    else:
        pass

def ip():
    ip = entry_ip.get()
    SERVER_ADDRESS = ip
    return SERVER_ADDRESS

# Get the port from the enter port
def port():
    ep = entry_port.get()
    print(ep)
    try:
        port = int(ep)
    except ValueError as e:
        port = 1234

    SERVER_PORT = port
    return SERVER_PORT

def server_port1():
    ep = entry_port.get()
    print(ep)
    try:
        serverport = int(ep)
    except ValueError as e:
        serverport = 1234

    SERVER_PORT = serverport
    return SERVER_PORT

def server_ip1():
    server_ip = entry_ip.get()
    SERVER_ADDRESS = server_ip
    return SERVER_ADDRESS

def usernames():
    usernames = entry_name.get()
    username = usernames
    return username

def chat_gui_button_wrapper():
    server_boot(server_ip1(), server_port1())
    chat_gui(ip(), port(), usernames())

# playsound.playsound('welcomecopy.mp3')

# Sets the theme to light
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode('light')

# set up the main window
root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry('300x500')
root.title('Sign On')

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(5, weight=2)
root.rowconfigure(6, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(7, weight=1)

# add a label to the window
label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root, text="COL Instant Messenger", font=("Times New Roman Pixel", 25))

# load images.
canvas = customtkinter.CTkCanvas(root)
directory = Path.home()
im = Image.open(f"{directory}/PycharmProjects/Messaging-APP/image/colloginscreen.png").resize((300, 250))
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
canvas.create_image(150, 100, image=logo)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=3)
# 506x462

# sets up the entry box for username input

entry_name = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=root, placeholder_text="ScreenName...", font=("Times New Roman Pixel", 15),
                                    width=150)
entry_name.grid(column=1, row=4)

entry_ip = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=root, placeholder_text="Enter IP...", font=("Times New Roman Pixel", 15),
                                  width=150)
entry_ip.grid(column=1, row=5)

entry_port = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=root, placeholder_text="Enter Port...", font=("Times New Roman Pixel", 15),
                                    width=150)
entry_port.grid(column=1, row=6)

# Add a button to the window
button = customtkinter.CTkButton(root, text='Sign On', fg_color="#d3d333", border_color="black", text_color="black",
                                 font=("Times New Roman Pixel", 15), command=chat_gui_button_wrapper)
button.grid(column=1, row=7)

# start the main loop
root.mainloop()
```

Here is the functions code for server and the actual chat gui:

```
# function version of gui to go into updated sign in page
def chat_gui(ip, port, usernames):
    # imports
    import customtkinter as ctk
    import socket
    import threading

    # server  address and port
    SERVER_ADDRESS = ip
    SERVER_PORT = port
    username = usernames

    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT))
    client_socket.setblocking(False)

    # GUI WINDOW size and appearance
    chat = ctk.CTk()
    chat.geometry('900x600')
    chat.title('COL Instant Messenger')
    ctk.set_appearance_mode('light')

    # Press enter to send message
    def handle_return_key(event):
        send_message()

    # send message function used in the button
    def send_message():

        message = f'{username}: {message_entry.get()}'
        message_entry.delete(0, len(message))

        client_socket.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

    # columns and row configuration
    chat.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    chat.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    chat.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

    chat.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
    chat.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    chat.rowconfigure(2, weight=2)
    chat.rowconfigure(3, weight=3)
    chat.rowconfigure(4, weight=0)

    # message entry box
    message_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(master=chat, placeholder_text="Message Here...", font=("Times New Roman Pixel", 15),
                                 width=300)
    message_entry.bind(sequence='<Return>', command=handle_return_key)

    message_entry.grid(row=4, column=2, columnspan=1, sticky="ew", pady=20)

    # send message button
    send_button = ctk.CTkButton(chat, text="send", command=send_message, hover=True, width=100)
    send_button.grid(row=4, column=3, columnspan=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="ew")

    # textbox, currently not working for some reason, won't print message into it,
    textbox = ctk.CTkTextbox(chat)
    textbox.configure(font=("Times New Roman Pixel", 15))
    textbox.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='nsew')

    textbox_client_list = ctk.CTkTextbox(chat)
    textbox_client_list.configure(font=("Times New Roman Pixel", 15))
    textbox_client_list.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='nsew')

    # insert code for receiving new network messages
    def received_messages():
        while True:
            try:
                # Receive the echoed message from the server
                received_message = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                client_socket.close()

                # Display the received message in the GUIs textbox
                textbox.configure(state='normal', text_color="black")
                textbox.insert("end", f"Received: {received_message}\n")
                textbox.configure(state="disabled", text_color="black",
                                  font=("Times New Roman Pixel", 15))  # configure textbox to be read-only
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                break

    send_receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=received_messages)
    send_receive_thread.start()

    # updates chat
    while True:
        chat.update_idletasks()
        chat.update()
        try:
            received_message = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if received_message:
                textbox.configure(state="normal")
                textbox.insert("end", f"{received_message}\n")
                textbox.configure(state="disabled")

        except Exception as e:
            pass
            # print(e)
            # break
    # chat.mainloop()


def server_gui(server_ip, server_port):
    import socket
    import threading
    from threading import Lock
    import select

    # Servers address and port (inputted)
    def set_address_and_port():
        global SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT
        SERVER_ADDRESS = server_ip
        SERVER_PORT = server_port
        return SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT

    # client handler that should echo the clients message back
    data_lock = Lock()
    connected_clients: list[(str, socket.socket, threading.Thread)] = []

    # connected_clients: dict(str, (socket, threading)) = {}

    def start_server():
        server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        server_socket.bind((SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT))
        server_socket.listen(5)
        print(f"Server is listening on {SERVER_ADDRESS}:{SERVER_PORT}")

        while True:
            server_socket.settimeout(5.0)
            try:
                client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
                # Give this a time-out so it doesn't block forever
            except TimeoutError:
                pass
            else:
                # If a client connected, do the stuff below
                print(f"Client connected: {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}")

                list_of_addresses = [addy for (addy, _, _) in connected_clients]

                if client_address[0] not in list_of_addresses:
                    client_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket, client_address))
                    connected_clients.append((client_address[0], client_socket, client_thread))
                    client_thread.start()
                    # Save the client thread in connected_clients so, we can check if its alive

                else:
                    for (addy, sock, thread) in connected_clients:
                        if addy == client_address[0]:
                            sock.close()
                            # Kill the thread...

            # Once you've dealt with any connections, check for any disconnections:
            for (address, client_socket, thread) in connected_clients:
                # If the thread for this client is not alive, remove it from connected_clients
                if not thread.is_alive():
                    # Remove this client from connected_clients
                    if client_socket in connected_clients:
                        connected_clients.remove((address, client_socket, thread))
                        break

    def disconnect(client_socket):
        client_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)

    def relay_message(client_address, message):
        print(f"Received from {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}: {message}")

        def send_to_one_client(user_sock):
            _, ready_write, in_error = select.select([], [user_sock], [user_sock])
            if user_sock in ready_write and not (user_sock in in_error):
                user_sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
            else:
                print("Could not send to client...")

        # map iterates over 'shared memory' so
        with data_lock:
            for (_, user_socket, _) in connected_clients:
                send_to_one_client(user_socket)

    # client handler that should echo the clients message back
    def handle_client(client_socket, client_address):
        while True:
            try:
                ready_read, _, in_error = select.select([client_socket], [], [client_socket])
                if client_socket in in_error:
                    print("Error reading from socket...")
                    break
                elif client_socket in ready_read:
                    message = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')

                    if message:
                        relay_message(client_address, message)
                    else:
                        print('No data received on read. Closing client connection')
                        client_socket.close()
                        return

            except select.error as e:  # No data to receive
                print('Socket error. Closing socket')
                print(e)
                client_socket.close()
                return

        # client_socket.close()
        # with data_lock:
        #     for item in connected_clients:
        #         (addy, socket) = item
        #         if socket == client_socket:
        #             connected_clients.remove(item)
        #             break

    # starts the server again

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        set_address_and_port(ip, port)
        start_server()
```

Comment: Code inside `if __name__ == "__main__"` block will not be executed if the file is imported.